# object pdflatex not found on Windows 7

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown, miktex

I work with RStudio (version 3.1.2). When I try to Knit PDF in my R Markdown script, I receive the following output:

> Error in eval(expr,envir,enclos): object 'pdflatex' not found

I have installed MikTex basic and have searched solutions on the web. There is one in stackoverflow for Mac users, I work with Windows 7.  It seems the problem is not having a path to the Tex installation. I found this brief guide to solve it on Windows: [enter link description here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/building-r-packages-missing-path-to-pdflatex/)

So, I did what it says: `Sys.which("pdflatex")` and received:

> pdflatex

```
  ""
```

Ten I typed: `Sys.getenv("PATH")`, obtaining:

> [1](http://www.r-bloggers.com/building-r-packages-missing-path-to-pdflatex/) "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;:/usr/texbin:/usr/texbin"

Finally, I entered: `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/usr/texbin",sep=":"))`, but when I try to knit PDF again it shows me the same error message. Thanks for all your time, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try setting `sep=";"` instead of `sep=":"`

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on a 64 bit Windows, so the `Sys.which("pdflatex")` returned:

```
 C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
```

Type in `sessionInfo()`. You should se something like this:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Depending on your system the path could be either: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` (for the 32-bit version) or `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` (for the 64-bit version).

Answer (score 1):

Edit your PATH variable. You're on windows, but you've tried to add a UNIX-style directory (i.e., separated from the other directories by `:` and using `/` rather than `\`). `'/usr/texbin/'` is probably not a directory on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your path. It might look like this `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` assuming you're working on a x64 OS. After that, open a cmd console and check if is everthing ok with this command: `pdflatex.exe -version`. Then restart RStudio and try to render your pdf again.